# Why does the interrupt not work after pressing the button

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt

Implement interrupt processing when the button is pressed, and the very start on the rising edge, the interrupt pin and to which the button is connected 11. Why does the interrupt not work after pressing the button?

```
#include <PinChangeInterrupt.h>

const uint8_t buttonPin = 11;
volatile bool buttonPressed = false;

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachPCINT(buttonPin, buttonISR, RISING);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (buttonPressed) {
    Serial.println("Button pressed!");
    buttonPressed = false;
  }
}

void buttonISR() {
  buttonPressed = true;
}
```

Model: [image]

Comment: The termination on the oscilloscope may be enough to pull down Pin 11.  Consider removing the oscilloscope from Pin 11 and repeating the test. If that works, I'll create an answer with more details and things to try.

Comment: Removed the oscilloscope from pin 11, still does not work

Comment: Have you tried attachInterrupt instead? https://reference.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/ note the use of digitalPinToInterrupt and that only certain pins on each model can be used as such. If it works, likely a bug in your PinChangeInterrupt.h or what it ties to.

Comment: I tried  `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonPin), buttonISR, FALLING)` also does not work

Comment: See https://reference.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/ Note that GPIO 11 does NOT appear in the column of the table listing pins that can be used to generate interrupts (except for nano 33 IOT, Zero and the 101) - suggest you use 2 or 3. If you want an interrupt on the RISING edge, use a PULL DOWN resistor. https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2020/02/21/pull-up-resistor-vs-pull-down-differences-arduino-guide/  that way pressing the button, rather than releasing the button produces the int. Finally, acknowledge that the button will bounce.

Comment: But pin 11 is the PCINT3 interrupt?

Comment: Which board are you using? Here is a nice simple example of doing something similar - it may help https://roboticsbackend.com/arduino-interrupts/ (I should have added at least one more board to that list).

Comment: I  am using arduino uno, the task is as follows: The button must be connected to the corresponding pin interrupt PCINT3.Does the task mean which pins trigger the PCINT3 interrupt, then it would be possible to connect to 3 or 2 pins

Comment: I guess I need to do through Pin Change Interrupts, something like this: `void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  PCMSK0 |= (1 << PCINT3);
  PCIFR |= (1 << PCIE0);    
 attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonPin), buttonISR, RISING);  
  Serial.begin(9600);
}`  but it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, but I can't interpret your task for you. Here is another good reference that may help. https://gammon.com.au/interrupts You will figure it out.

Comment: is it possible to do button click tracking via Pin Change Interrupts?

Comment: Notice the slight difference between your attachPCINT and in the [example](https://github.com/NicoHood/PinChangeInterrupt/blob/master/examples/PinChangeInterrupt_Led/PinChangeInterrupt_Led.ino#L45). There is extra digitalPinToPCINT, basically you are probably catching radio on some other pin.

Comment: @GoodYork, I understand you have not done any of this with real hardware.  That the question is based on an emulation only?  You should have said so in the question.  Please go back end edit your question stating clearly that the question is based only on am emulation.  (If you are wondering why an emulation does not reflect the real world ... perhaps we should start by saying that companies like Atmel (now Microchip) are very unlikely to disclose everything about their processor's design.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested proper code with some changes:

```cpp
#include <PinChangeInterrupt.h>

const uint8_t buttonPin = 11;

volatile bool buttonPressed = false;

void buttonISR() {
  buttonPressed = true;
}


void loop() {
  if (buttonPressed) {
    delay(20);
    buttonPressed = false;

    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, !digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachPCINT(digitalPinToPCINT(buttonPin), buttonISR, RISING);

  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}
```

And with `attachPCINT(digitalPinToPCINT(buttonPin), buttonISR, RISING);` it works flawlessly. Only difference is that `digitalPinToPCINT` (as every example for PinChangeInterrupt library tries to suggest).

You also tried attachInterrupt + digitalPinToInterrupt with the pin 11, but Arduino Uno has only two external interrupt capable pins D2 and D3. So it couldn't work with D11. It also depends on MCU (see [attachInterrupt() reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/)).

The PCINT is more or less related to the old AVRs like Atmega328 or Atmega2560. And PCINT in Atmega2560 isn't available on all port (it uses ISR per port and it has many ports.

If the proteus simulator is the cause, you can also ommit the ISR (as you are not doing anything big here) and just poll the pin:

```
const uint8_t buttonPin = 11;
bool buttonPressed = false;

void loop() {
  bool pinHigh = (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH);

  if (pinHigh && buttonPressed) { // button released
    delay(20);
    buttonPressed = false;
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, !digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));
  } else if (!pinHigh && !buttonPressed) {
    buttonPressed = true;
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}
```

Comment: Just to amplify on this, `digitalPinToInterrupt` is for pins D2 and D3 on the Uno (this function returns 0 or 1 respectively) when used with `attachInterrupt`, however `digitalPinToPCINT` is for the **Pin Change** interrupts, which the OP is using.

Comment: Why doesn't work for me, I use arduino uno

Comment: @GoodYork you have to change:  `attachPCINT(buttonPin, buttonISR, RISING);` to `attachPCINT(digitalPinToPCINT(buttonPin), buttonISR, RISING);`  or just try to use my code (It's toggling onboard LED - it has really simple debouncing too)

Comment: I copied your code, just replaced LED on with `Serial.println` and something is not working for me

Comment: Maybe wiring issue. Or if you are trying it only in emulator, it's not usually working very well with ISRs

Comment: I do it in the Proteus emulator

Comment: @GoodYork Please take a photograph of your wiring, and amend your question to include that photograph.

Comment: @NickGammon I only have the model that is already attached to the question

Comment: *I do it in the Proteus emulator* - you did not disclose that in your question. Emulators **may not faithfully reproduce** what happens in real life. Your problem is therefore in the emulator. Try using a real Arduino.

Comment: *I only have the model that is already attached to the question* - if you have an emulator then you don't even have that. I read the question and saw that you claimed you were using an Arduino Uno.

Comment: *Why doesn't work for me, I use arduino uno* - you should have said "I use Arduino Uno in the Proteus emulator". One is a real piece of hardware that behaves in a predictable way that we can all test. The other is a piece of software.

Comment: then, it's just not possible to do it in the emulator?

Comment: You can do it without interrupts, I'm usually just polling button pins every few milliseconds. Added code without isr

Comment: @KIIV  *the task is as follows: The button must be connected to the corresponding pin interrupt PCINT3* - they have a task, which is to use PCINT3. The task isn't to solve any real-world problem.